# Load extras on second css

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my first try with js and I have got the scripts from google and my lecturer.

What I want to do is to load a slideshow script whenever *n* "second" passes and switch the css(one of two stylesheets). When going back to "first" slide, the slideshow should not be loaded.

```js
/* Quick hack for switching a CSS file by mouse click. (C) DJ 8/2012 */
function switchCSS(first, second) {
    var styleLink = document.getElementById("replaceLink");
    var href = styleLink.getAttribute("href");
    newHref = href == first ? second : first;
    styleLink.setAttribute("href", newHref);
}
```

Slideshow:

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();


function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 3500); // Change image every 3.5 seconds
}
```

Comment: - fixing  small mistake in the code (wrapping functions with {}) 
- rephrasing question to make it more understandable (still I cannot understand)

Comment: Thanks for answering! I have two css. On the "first" I do not want to load the "slideshow". But on the "second" the slideshow javascript should kick in. It is a button in HTML that changes from the first to the second style, and as user go back again with same button the slideshow-code should be turned off again.